# Why incorrect number of tokens are sent according to the current rate to the contributor.?

Tags: remix, balances, fallback-function

Token Contract
https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x6f5c43f62b4b18aa8ed37b42f2804f7049cbe0e9#code

CrowdSale Contract
https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x9b94e1894abe2051e6e96bf1b57fe5d3adbbc5aa#code

Environment == Injected Web3 Ropsten MetaMask/Remix

Call Functions as follow :

1. setTokenOffering (offeringAddr: CrowdSale address),
2. Sent 0.1 ETH TO CrowdSale contract (successfull),
   -amountRaised == 0: uint256: 100000000000000000
   -balanceOf == 0: uint256: 100000000000000000
   -tokenBalanceOf == 0: uint256: 680000000000000000000 / rate = 0: uint256: 6800
   [image]

3.enableTransfer,

4.Transfer (to tokenReward address == 210 000 000 PDT ) (successfull),

5.approve (allowance == 210 000 000 PDT),

6.transferFrom (from:owner address, to: rewardAddress, value:0 (only with value "0" works)
Im not sure about that !, but is Success;

It shows me 0.1 PDT instead of 680 PDT. 
[image]

Has anyone seen something similar and could help me overcome this problem.

I am asking for a straightforward answer. Thank You.Robert

7.(fallback) and "buy" give me "Gas estimation failed".
[image]

Comment: Where do you actually transfer tokens in your crowdsale contract?

Comment: Hi, tokens was transfer to the token reward address.