# The funds sent to the contract do not show the correct value on the side of the contributor.?

Tags: solidity, remix, balances

The question is not answered that's why I ask again.
Can someone tell me and point out ( correct me) where the problem lies.

Eth has been sent to the crowdsale contract successfully. BalanceOf and amountrised were calculated correctly. Unfortunately, shows with the error on the side of the contributor. 
[image]
Why is this happening? What did I miss here? Thank You Robert.

Token Contract
https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x6f5c43f62b4b18aa8ed37b42f2804f7049cbe0e9#code

CrowdSale Contract
https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x9b94e1894abe2051e6e96bf1b57fe5d3adbbc5aa#code

Environment == Injected Web3 Ropsten MetaMask/Remix

More details are here.
[Why incorrect number of tokens are sent according to the current rate to the contributor.?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/49719/why-incorrect-number-of-tokens-are-sent-according-to-the-current-rate-to-the-con)

Comment: Where do you actually transfer tokens in your crowdsale contract?

Comment: Hi, tokens was transfer to the token reward address.

Comment: I mean, where in contract code do you transfer tokens?

Comment: I can only add Comment, Look yourself here; // The token being sold
    
ParadiseToken public tokenReward;  - line 432

address addressOfTokenUsedAsReward   -line 473

tokenReward = ParadiseToken(addressOfTokenUsedAsReward);  -486

Comment: Ok. But I don't see any token transfer functionality in crowdsale contract source code, so token balance can't be changed after investment.

Comment: Any suggestions that help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You have no tokens transfer functionality in the crowdsale contract, so tokens balance of the investor address can't be changed after investment. You should modify `buy()` method and add tokens transfer functionality to it.

```
function buy ()
        payable public
        whenNotPaused
        beforeDeadline
        afterStartTime
        saleNotClosed
    {
        require(msg.value >= minContribution);
        uint amount = msg.value;

        // Compute the number of tokens to be rewarded to the sender
        // Note: it's important for this calculation that both wei
        // and PDT have the same number of decimal places (18)
        uint numTokens = amount.mul(rate);

        // --- NEW CODE STARTS HERE -------------------------------------------

        require(tokenReward.transfer(msg.sender, numTokens));

        // --- NEW CODE ENDS HERE ---------------------------------------------

        // update the total amount raised
        amountRaised = amountRaised.add(amount);

        // update the sender's balance of wei contributed
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = balanceOf[msg.sender].add(amount);
        // add to the token balance of the sender
        tokenBalanceOf[msg.sender] = tokenBalanceOf[msg.sender].add(numTokens);

        FundTransfer(msg.sender, amount, true);
        // Check if the funding goal or cap have been reached
        checkFundingGoal();
        checkFundingCap();
    }
```

In addition to make this code workable you should transfer some tokens cap to the crowdsale contract address. If you don't want to do that and want keep all tokens on some separate `ASSET_MANAGER_WALLET` address, then you should `approve` some tokens amount from this address to crowdsale contract address and instead of  call `transfer` function you should call `transferFrom` function.

`require(tokenReward.transferFrom(ASSET_MANAGER_WALLET, msg.sender, numTokens))`

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
After adding the code:  require(tokenReward.transfer(msg.sender, numTokens));, l can not send eth to crowdsale (out of gas). Try to do the test yourself you will see.

Comment: Your crowd sale contract does not have any tokens, that's why it cannot send them out.